# Searching class-intersections of many hierarchies for maximum/minimum values

Tags: multilevel-analysis

Suppose we have some data for a large number of people (e.g. salary).

Suppose further, that each person is classified in several hierarchical groups.

E.g. they are classified by their location (Toronto < Ontario < Canada), and by their role (Software Engineer < IT). Anyone who lives in Toronto, also lives in Ontario, and anyone who is a Software engineer is also in IT.

Now, what is the most efficient way to find out what intersection (e.g. Luxembourg, Investment Banker) contains the people with the highest average salary?

(Simpson's paradox leads me to believe I need to brute force search, but I'm not sure.)

Please note I asked this same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27262813/searching-class-intersections-of-many-hierarchies-for-maximum-minimum-values

Comment: "Most efficient" can be measured in several contrasting ways. Presumably you mean in terms of amount of computation, but even then do you mean in terms of the worst-case situation or perhaps an average over some kind of ensemble of possible inputs? Only in the latter situation will anything other than brute force (exhaustive enumeration) be worth considering. But then, what would you propose for the probability distribution of the ensemble? And do you intend to account for precomputation of things like factor indexes for each group, or will these assumed to be given at the outset?

Comment: @whuber, I do mean in terms of computation. Of course it's customary to first consider average case performance, and possibly worst case performance when evaluating algorithms. With brute force, complexity grows as the product of hierarchy cardinalities. The cost to find users in an intersection groups will not grow at this rate. So I suspect any efficiencies will be gained by not having to consider all group intersections. I don't know what the term "factor indexes" means.

Comment: Creating a "factor" effectively hashes each group identifier into an integral index. With that done, complexity does not grow with group cardinalities at all: the entire procedure is completed in a single pass through the data, no matter how many groups there are. It requires $O(n)$ worst-case effort for $n$ data records because at each step the sum and count for the group intersection are both accessed and modified in $O(1)$ time and a running maximum of the means is optionally updated in $O(1)$ time. BTW, you cannot consider average performance until you specify a distribution of inputs.

Comment: Of course. I was thinking from the perspective of of the groups. I see now if I iterate through users this can be done in linear time. Thanks.